# Find the coordinates of a polynomial relative to a given basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

> The set $B=\{−4−3x^2, −16−3x−12x^2, −35−9x−27x^2\}$ is a basis for $P_3$ (or $\Bbb R_3[x]$, if you wish.) Find the coordinates of $p(x)=−160−39x−123x^2$ relative to the basis $B$.

What I did to try to solve this problem was:

I let $x = 1$ making the set $B$ into a matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}-4&0&-3\\-16&-3&-12\\-35&-9&-27\end{bmatrix}

Then I transposed it:
\begin{bmatrix}-4&-16&-3\\0&-3&-12\\-3&-12&-27\end{bmatrix}

Then I made a matrix out of $p(x)$:
\begin{bmatrix}-160\\-39\\-123\end{bmatrix}

Then I multiplied the two matrices and received:
\begin{bmatrix}5569\\1224\\4269\end{bmatrix}

But this answer is wrong!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to take the inverse of the matrix before you multiply it by your vector.  What you want is a mix of the three basis polynomials that gives you $p(x)$; instead, what you've done is treated the coefficients of $p(x)$ as a mix, and computed what polynomial that gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of the right ingredients here, but it's worth seeing *why* these
ingredients are correct.

We have the basis
$$
\beta=\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}
$$
of $\Bbb R_2[x]$ where $f_1, f_2, f_3\in\Bbb R_2[x]$ are given by
\begin{align*}
  f_1(x) &= -3 \, x^{2} - 4 & f_2(x) &= -12 \, x^{2} - 3 \, x - 16 & f_3(x) &= -27 \, x^{2} - 9 \, x - 35
\end{align*}
We wish to compute the vector $[p]_\beta$ where $p\in\Bbb R_2[x]$ is given by
$p(x)=-123 \, x^{2} - 39 \, x - 160$.

Our desired vector $[p]_\beta$ is defined as $[p]_\beta=\langle c_1, c_2, c_3\rangle$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\Bbb R$ satisfy the equation
$$
c_1\cdot f_1+c_2\cdot f_2+c_3\cdot f_3 = p
$$
To find these scalars, note that this equation takes the form
$$
c_1\cdot(-3 \, x^{2} - 4)
+c_2\cdot(-12 \, x^{2} - 3 \, x - 16)
+c_3\cdot(-27 \, x^{2} - 9 \, x - 35)
=
-123 \, x^{2} - 39 \, x - 160
$$
Rearranging this equation gives
$$
(-3 \, c_{1} - 12 \, c_{2} - 27 \, c_{3})\cdot x^2
+(-3 \, c_{2} - 9 \, c_{3})\cdot x
+(-4 \, c_{1} - 16 \, c_{2} - 35 \, c_{3})
=
-123 \, x^{2} - 39 \, x - 160
$$
Comparing coefficients on both sides of our equation then gives the system
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
  -3\,c_1 &-& 12\,c_2 &-& 27\,c_3 &=& -123 \\
          & & -3\,c_2 &-&  9\,c_3 &=&  -39 \\
  -4\,c_1 &-& 16\,c_2 &-& 35\,c_3 &=& -160
\end{array}
$$
This system is represented by the augmented matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-3 & -12 & -27 & -123 \\
0 & -3 & -9 & -39 \\
-4 & -16 & -35 & -160
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row reducing then gives
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-3 & -12 & -27 & -123 \\
0 & -3 & -9 & -39 \\
-4 & -16 & -35 & -160
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right]
$$
This gives our desired vector $[p]_\beta=\langle 1, 1, 4\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

You should inverse the matrix, not transpose it.

But it is more efficient to solve the linear system.

$$\begin{bmatrix}-4&0&-3\\-16&-3&-12\\-35&-9&-27\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-160\\-39\\-123\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Actually, the answer was correct when I transposed it, took the inverse of it, then multiplied it be the 3x1 matrix, p(x).